# smart card pin out

Tags: smart-card

Following is the image of the smart card which I am using. Can I get the pin configuration?

And what kind of memory IC can we fit inside this card. How to find inside IC?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link that explain quite well what the pinout is.

http://pinoutsguide.com/Memory/SmartCardIso_pinout.shtml

And by experience the IC inside these kind of cards are simply a little DIE package right under the connector

[Here's is a picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Smartcard_chip_structure_and_packaging_EN.svg) of the actual structure of a smart card

And here is a list of what type of cards you can find

[Smart Card Types](http://www.smartcardbasics.com/smart-card-types.html)

Comment: Is that EEPROM ic?

Comment: From little research it depends on the type of cards, maybe you'll have a datasheet for your card

http://www.smartcardbasics.com/smart-card-types.html

Comment: I believe that most smart cards have a security chip which uses an encrypted challenge-response system. This is to prevent cloning a card.

Comment: From my little knowledge on this subjet, I think it depends on what type of card, there is some that you can read/write but some other type that you can only read (read-only) the encryption depends on what card you're using I guess